# Transform list of inequalities into matrix form $A\ x \leq b$

Tags: functions, matrix, linear-algebra, inequalities

I have a list of linear inequalities, and I want to get it into the form  $A\ x \leq b$; i.e., find the matrix $A$ and the vector $b$. Is there any function in *Mathematica* that can that can do this?

Comment: Could you add a small, complete example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically it amounts to using `CoefficientArrays` along with a bit of massaging for sense of inequality.

```
getLinearForm[ineqs : {(_LessEqual | _GreaterEqual) ..}, vars_] := 
 Module[
  {mults, lpolys, rhs, lhs},
  mults = Map[Head, ineqs] /. {LessEqual -> 1, GreaterEqual -> -1};
  lpolys = mults*Apply[Subtract, ineqs, {1}];
  {rhs, lhs} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[lpolys, vars]];
  {lhs, -rhs}
  ]
```

Quick example.

```
vars = {x, y};
ineqs = {a x + b y <= 3, c x + d y >= 7};

getLinearForm[ineqs, vars]

(* Out[302]= {{{a, b}, {-c, -d}}, {3, -7}} *)
```